# Hubot Message Only Specific Channel On Enter/Leave

Tags: coffeescript, slack, hubot

Working on creating a list of messages that Hubot can randomly choose from to display in the #general channel when someone joins the company. I've got the message part working, but it's doing it on ANY channel... how can I limit it to just a specific channel? One step further, would like to take the users name who entered and paste it inside the sentences if possible.

Thanks!

```
validWelcome = [
      'We have a new kid on the block, Hello!'
      'Welcome the newest member to the team!'
      'Thanks for joining us!'
      'Happy to have you here!'
    ]

  module.exports = (robot) ->
    robot.enter (msg) ->
      msg.send {room: '#integration-test'}, msg.random validWelcome
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues to consider

1. Does the chat software you are using expose enough information to Hubot via the adapter when a user joins a room (see [docs](https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/#entering-and-leaving))
2. Do you want to display this message if someone leaves and re-joins the #general room?

Taking a wild guess that you are using Slack you can see what the Slack adaptor sends you [here](https://github.com/slackapi/hubot-slack/blob/master/src/bot.coffee#L186).  You really want access to `channel.name` but you can get `channel.id` from `msg.room` and take it from there and solve #1.  If you're not using Slack find the source for your adapter and search for `EnterMessage`.

If you want to solve #2 you'll need to do something clever with Hubot's [brain](https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/#persistence) and record the fact that you've sent a welcome for each user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes using Slack.

I don't believe anyone is able to leave the #general room, as many people have asked before. So I don't think I'll need to do anything for that occurring.

Thanks for the input, I'll work on it some more and let you know!

Comment: You're welcome, I think if you just hard-code the slack channel id you'll be fine